# In a Bayesian MCMC model, if we plug the average of posterior draws back into the Likelihood, would it be estimating the Posterior Predictive?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior

Suppose we have a Bayesian model with data $y$ and a parameter to be estimated, $\theta$. Then the posterior is written as:

$$
p(\theta | y) \propto p(y|\theta)p(\theta)
$$

Suppose that we used an MCMC to obtain draws of the posterior, $p(\theta | y)$. Suppose we then take the average of these draws and then plug the average back into the likelihood, $p(y|\theta)$, and plot it across the support on $y$. Would this distribution be approximating the posterior predictive? Or is it approximating something completely different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The posterior predictive is approximated by the average of the sampling densities over the MCMC sample
$$p(y|y^\text{obs})\approx\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T p(y|\theta^{(t)})$$
To simulate from this distribution, one need pick one of the $\theta^{(t)}$ at random and simulate $Y$ from the corresponding $p(y|\theta^{(t)})$ [and not *for all* the $\theta^{(t)}]$.

Comment: If I wanted to build the histogram of the simulated distribution, it seems there are two approaches. The first (yours), is randomly picking $\theta^{(t)}$ at random, simulate $Y$, iterate this many times, then plot the $Y$'s I get. The second, seems to be picking $\theta^{(1)}$, simulating $Y^{(1)}$, picking $\theta^{(2)}$, simulating $Y^{(2)}$, etc, until I get $T$ such $Y$'s and getting their histogram. This second one doesn't pick the $\theta^{(t)}$'s randomly, is it the same? What is the purpose of choosing $\theta^{(t)}$ randomly (which I also assume is by replacement)?

Comment: If you want to draw/plot the approximate distribution, you simply need averaging the $p(y|\theta^{(t)})$'s, there is no need to draw/simulate $Y_i$'s. If you want to exactly draw/simulate from the approximate predictive [rhs], sampling with replacement is needed.

Comment: @Xi’an I’m a bit puzzled by “not for all”. Why not do a prediction as the final step of each iteration? I thought this was the standard way.

Answer (score 4):

No. You'd have* to simulate from the likelihood for each (or at least a representative subset of) MCMC samples to obtain samples from the posterior predictive distribution. Otherwise your uncertainty would not matter - plus many models are highly non-linear.

* There are of course alternative approaches.

Comment: Thanks, would the above method of averaged parameters serve as an approximation?

Comment: No (unless there is essentially no uncertainty around the parameter). Perhaps sampling from a (possibility multivariate) normal distribution around the mean might work for some suitable transformation (e.g. often for the logit of a single probability).